# multiple components using the same templateurl

Tags: angular, controls, custom-controls

I am trying to find the best solution for this problem, basically I have 4 components that use the exact same html but the logic is different in the ts file.

what I need is the 4 components to have the same html tempalate.

is it okay to use the same `templateUrl` for more than one component ?
if not what is the best approach to achieve the same effect?

I am using angular 12.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to use the same templateUrl, You may need some adjustments in folders structure.

For example You can do something like

```
├── myComponent
│   └── myComponent.html
│       myComponent1
│       ├── myComponent1.ts
│       └── myComponent1.spec.ts
│       myComponent2
│       ├── myComponent2.ts
│       └── myComponent2.spec.ts
```

Other possibility (to use when You have similarities in logic as well) is to have base component and extend it in child components like:

```
.
├── myComponent
│   ├── myComponent.base.ts
│   └── myComponent.html
│       myComponent1
│       ├── myComponent1.ts (extends myComponent.base.ts)
│       └── myComponent1.spec.ts
│       myComponent2
│       ├── myComponent2.ts (extends myComponent.base.ts)
│       └── myComponent2.spec.ts
```

Comment: is this considered bad design ?
it feels to me like it is, if it is what kind of effect would it have on my project ?

Comment: What do you mean by bad design? From external part of application it's just a component, it'll not care about where template is taken from, inside it's reusing template as expected, it has no effect on project it's just example of structuring your component.

Comment: Of course example is minimal it does not contain modules and external parts of application, it all depends on your use case.